# STM32F0 SPI loopback - No data on MISO

Tags: stm32, spi

I am trying to loopback the SPI bus on my STM32F0 (with a discovery board, *MISO* pin connected to *MOSI* pin).

I am following the tutorial [Discovering the STM32 Microcontroller](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~geobrown/book.pdf), (edition January 18, 2014), *Exercise 6.1 : SPILoopback*.

The STM32 is configured as the master.

To send a byte to MOSI pin, the author wrote :

```c
SPI_I2S_SendData (SPIx, *tbuf++);
```

where :

- *SPIx* is the SPI bus I want to send data
- *tbuf* is the *uint8* (in other words an *unsigned char* ...) I want to send on the bus

To receive this byte from MISO pin, he wrote :

```c
while (SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus (SPIx, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET);
if (rbuf)
{
    *rbuf++ = SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPIx);
...
...
```

The flag *SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE* should be *SET* since I send a data to *MOSI* pin, and since *MOSI* pin is connected to *MISO* pin.

### My problem is :

I never go out from the *while* loop (the *SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE* is never *SET*, even if I look through the debugger.

(I see *CLK* and *MOSI* being alive on my logic analyser, so I'm sure my byte goes out from an electrical point of view.)

It is like the STM32 never received the byte, even if *MISO* pin is connected on *MOSI* pin ...

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because on *STM32F0*, the flag *SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE* is set by default only when 16 bits (so 2 bytes) are received on *MISO* pin.

If you send 2 bytes and **then** do you *while* loop, you should exit of the loop very quickly.

The *Reference Manual* said (Section *SPI status flags*) :

> The RXNE flag is set depending on the FRXTH bit value in the SPIx_CR2 register:
>
> - If FRXTH is set, RXNE goes high and stays high until the RXFIFO level is greater or equal to 1/4 (8-bit).
> - If FRXTH is cleared, RXNE goes high and stays high until the RXFIFO level is greater than or equal to 1/2 (16-bit).

So, if you want the flag *SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE* to be set when only 1 byte is received, you should use the following function :

```c
SPI_RxFIFOThresholdConfig (SPIx, SPI_RxFIFOThreshold_QF);
```

- SPI_RxFIFOThreshold_QF: RXNE event is generated if the FIFO level is greater or equal to 1/4.
- SPI_RxFIFOThreshold_HF: RXNE event is generated if the FIFO level is greater or equal to 1/2. (default value)